# <function attribute at 0x01F0FC70> in text file instead of values

Tags: python

I'm writing some code where I'm appending the return of a `def` statement to a text file multiple times but the value will change each time because the def statement has a random function in it.

Here is the code:

```
import random
def attribute():
    return str(10  + (random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4)))

with open("attributes.txt","w") as file:
    file.write("Charater\tSkill\tStrength")
    file.write("\nCharater1\t{0}\t{1}".format(attribute,attribute))
    file.write("\nCharater2\t{0}\t{1}".format(attribute,attribute))
```

This is the output of the text doc:

```
Charater    Skill   Strength
Charater1   <function attribute at 0x01F0FC70>  <function attribute at 0x01F0FC70>
Charater2   <function attribute at 0x01F0FC70>  <function attribute at 0x01F0FC70>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the function `attribute` itself, rather than calling it and passing the results. Your code needs the `()`:

```
file.write("\nCharater2\t{0}\t{1}".format(attribute(),attribute()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `attribute` function like this:

```
file.write("\nCharater1\t{0}\t{1}".format(attribute(),attribute()))
```

Notice the parens after `attribute`. Your current code references the function object, whose string representation is being written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the function object attribute instead of its return value attribute().

Add the parentheses and you'll be fine.